# How to use unittest to assert an assert?

Tags: python, testing, assert, python-unittest

Let's say I have this function:

```
def to_upper(var):
    assert type(var) is str, 'The input for to_upper should be a string'
    return var.upper()
```

And a file for unit testing using `unittest`:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        -- Code here --


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How do I test that if I call `to_upper(9)` it throws an assertion error?

Comment: On a side note, you may want to change `type(var) is str` to `isinstance(var, str)` to be more idiomatic and handle subclasses of `str`

Comment: Given that assertions can be disabled at runtime, this seems like a useless thing to test.

Comment: @chepner is probably right. Just let it be. `to_upper` will raise `AttributeError` "automatically` if `var` is not an `str` (given that it does not implement `upper`)

Answer (score 0):

You can assert an assertion with `assertRaises(AssertionError)`:

```
def test_1(self):
    with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
        to_upper(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assertions are for debugging. If there is some precondition that is important enough to verify with a unit test, check for it explicitly and raise a `ValueError` or `TypeError`, as appropriate, if it fails.

In this case, you don't actually care the `var` is a `str`, though; you just need it to have an `upper` method.

```
def to_upper(var):
    try:
        return var.upper()
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError("Argument has no method 'upper'")
```

Comment: maybe `TypeError` is more appropriate than `ValueError`?

Comment: Yeah, it would be.